# Which actors have played The Doctor over the years?

Tags: doctor-who, actors

I remember watching *Doctor Who* as a kid and they went through about 2-3 Doctors in that time.  And nowadays I think the new TV series have had one or two.

So how many different actors have played The Doctor, and who are they?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The other answer only lists the actors who have played Dr Who for an extended period in the BBC TV series. There are dozens more who have portrayed the Doctor in movies, specials, parodies, etc. -- see [here](http://doctorwhotoys.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=2257) for a much more complete list.

The list (with quite a lot of typos fixed) is:

#### Official

| Doctor | Regeneration |
| --- | --- |
| William Hartnell | 1st Doctor |
| Patrick Troughton | 2nd Doctor |
| Jon Pertwee | 3rd Doctor |
| Tom Baker | 4th Doctor |
| Peter Davison | 5th Doctor |
| Colin Baker | 6th Doctor |
| Sylvester McCoy | 7th Doctor |
| Paul McGann | 8th Doctor |
| John Hurt | The War Doctor |
| Christopher Eccleston | 9th Doctor |
| David Tennant | 10th Doctor |
| Matt Smith | 11th Doctor |
| Peter Capaldi | 12th Doctor |
| Jodie Whittaker | 13th Doctor |
| Jo Martin | Fugitive Doctor |

#### Unofficial

- Trevor Martin - (alternative 4th) Doctor in The Seven Keys to Doomsday
- Mark Gatiss - Doctor Who night parody Doctor
- Richard E Grant - alternative 9th "Shalka" Doctor
- Catherine Tate - The Friday Night Project Doctor
- Rowan Atkinson - Comic Relief 9th Doctor
- Richard E Grant - Comic Relief 10th Doctor
- Jim Broadbent - Comic Relief 11th Doctor
- Hugh Grant - Comic Relief 12th Doctor
- Joanna Lumley - Comic Relief 13th Doctor
- Lenny Henry - Parody Lenny Henry Show
- Geoffrey Bayldon - Unbound 1
- David Warner - Unbound 2
- David Collings - Unbound 3
- Michael Jayston - The Valeyard
- Arabella Weir - Unbound 6
- Peter Cushing - Doctor Who films
- David Tennant - Meta Crisis doctor
- Catherine Tate - The Doctor Donna
- Adrian Gibbs - the watcher
- Christopher Baker - Morbius Doctor 1
- Robert Holmes - Morbius Doctor 2
- Graeme Harper - Morbius Doctor 3
- Douglas Camfield - Morbius Doctor 4
- Philip Hinchcliffe - Morbius Doctor 5
- Robert Banks Stewart -Morbius Doctor 6
- George Gallaccio - Morbius Doctor 7
- Christopher Barry - Morbius Doctor 8
- David Morrisey - Jackson Lake
- Nick Briggs - The future Doctor
- NO ACTOR - the infinity Doctors
- Jim Broadbent - Victoria Wood parody Doctor
- Justin Lee Colins - Friday Night Project Doctor 2
- Paul McGann - Zagreus Doctor
- Richard Hurdnall - 1st doctor in The Five Doctors
- Jon Culshaw - Many Doctor Who parodies
- NO ACTOR - The Cabinet of Light Doctor
- David Banks - The Ultimate Adventure Doctor
- Clive Dunn - Doctor Fotherington (spoof)
- Ronnie Barker - The Two Ronnies spoof Doctor
- George Layton - Spoof 4th Doctor (the French and Saunders show)
- Steve Vizard - Fastforward (spoof) Doctor Hewson
- Vic Reeves - Third Doctor as Roger Daltrey
- Mark Lamarr - Fourth Doctor as Pete Townshend
- Bob Mortimer - First Doctor as John Entwistle
- Matt Lucas - Second Doctor as Keith Moon
- Mark Perry - Second Doctor Dead Ringers
- Kevin Connelly - Seventh Doctor Dead Ringers
- Phil Cornwell - Ninth Doctor Dead Ringers
- Todd Carty - the Charlotte Church show
- ?unknown actor - Gina's Laughing Gear parody 10th Doctor
- Sam and Mark - Doctor two TMI
- Trevor Martin - 3rd Doctor on stage (Jon Pertwee's Doctor)
- Tony Garner - Two and a half Doctor (devious)
- NO ACTOR - Muldwych
- NO ACTOR - The Relic
- Lance Curtis - Dr. Poo (radio show)
- Sam and Mark - Dr. Poo (TMI)
- Basil Brush - Basil's Swap Shop Doctor Who
- NO ACTOR (Dr Zoidberg) - The Spoof Doctor (Futurama comics)
- NO ACTOR - Doctor Poo (comic book character) (Viz)
- Edmund Warwick - Robot Dr.Who
- Toby Jones - The Dream Lord
- Nick Scovell - Stage Doctor
- Sylvester McCoy - Regenerating 6th Doctor
- David Bradley - Alternate 1st doctor
- George Watsky - 4th Doctor and Peter Shukoff (aka Nice Peter) - 10th Doctor on *Epic Rap Battles of History*

Comment: In one of UK comedian Harry Enfield's sketch shows from the 1990s, there was a one-off appearance by the angry Scouse "Doctor Who-Are-You-Looking-At". I haven't edited this into the answer yet because I don't know if it was Harry Enfield or Paul Whitehouse or someone else who played him. (The sketch is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RU36P6YNvGY)

Comment: And of course there are any number of Doctor Who-themed school plays ....

Comment: Anyway, why do you consider The Valeyard "unofficial"?

Comment: In the mid-70s there was a BBC schools education programme called "Mathsshow" which featured a Doctor Who parody called "Doctor Where", but I don't know the name of the actor playing the Doctor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXs8NBSWx1A

Comment: Late 1960s there was a sketch in The Jimmy Tarbuck show with Jimmy playing the Doctor. IIRC it featured Cilla Black dashing into a police box

Comment: Season 12 Finale, The Timeless Children, re-established the eight (8) “Morbius Doctors” as the Doctor’s incarnations. They were official when Brain of Morbius was produced, and now that has been reiterated in current TV canon.

Answer (score 14):

The "canon" Doctors in the BBC series are:

1. William Hartnell  1963–1966
2. Patrick Troughton       1966–1969
3. Jon Pertwee             1970–1974
4. Tom Baker               1974–1981
5. Peter Davison         1981–1984
6. Colin Baker         1984–1986
7. Sylvester McCoy         1987–1989, 1996
8. Paul McGann         1996
9. Christopher Eccleston 2005
10. David Tennant         2005–2010
11. Matt Smith         2010-2013
12. Peter Capaldi         2013-2017
13. Jodie Whittaker 2017-2022

And also the War Doctor, John Hurt (2013).

and don't forget to visit this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who

Comment: This is a complete list of "canon" doctors in the BBC TV series. Many other actors have played The Doctor in other media; most notably perhaps is Peter Cushing, who played the character in a number of movies in the 1960s.

Comment: @Nellius - for most fans, only the canon actors are accepted.

Comment: I was a schoolboy and happily went to the cinema with my mates to see both the Peter Cushing films. He had a TARDIS and there was Daleks. Canon or not, to us he was indeed the Doctor.

Answer (score 1):

Doctors mentioned in *Doctor Who*: "The Brain of Morbius", though proved as to not be the Doctor but just the Morbius lieing

First Doctor: William Hartnell 1963–1966

Second Doctor: Patrick Troughton 1966–1969

Third Doctor: Jon Pertwee 1970–1974

Fourth Doctor: Tom Baker 1974–1981

Fifth Doctor : Peter Davison 1981–1984

Sixth Doctor: Colin Baker 1984–1986

Seventh Doctor: Sylvester McCoy 1987–1996

Eighth Doctor: Paul McGann 1996

War Doctor: John Hurt 2013-2005
(Wibbly Wobbly Timey Wimey)

Ninth Doctor: Christopher Eccleston 2005

Tenth Doctor: David Tennant 2005–2010

David Tennants hand 2009ish to 2009

That human guy who thought he was the Doctor in *Doctor Who*: "The Next Doctor" (unremembered date)

Eleventh Doctor: Matt Smith 2010-2014

Twelfth Doctor: Peter Capaldi 2014-2018

Thirteen Doctor: Jodie Whitaker 2018-to whenever she regenerates

Answer (score 0):

William Hartnell - 1st Doctor

Patrick Troughton - 2nd Doctor

Jon Pertwee - 3rd Doctor

Tom Baker - 4th Doctor

Peter Davison - 5th Doctor

Colin Baker - 6th Doctor

Sylvester McCoy - 7th Doctor

Paul McGann - 8th Doctor

John Hurt - The War Doctor

Christopher Eccleston - 9th Doctor

David Tennant - 10th Doctor

Matt Smith - 11th Doctor

Peter Capaldi - 12th Doctor

Jodie Whittaker - 13th Doctor

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Apart from your... strange choice of username, I don't see what this adds to Mike Scott's answer from well over eight years ago. Answers should contribute something new rather than just repeating the same information. Also, you need to hit space twice for a line break, not just once.

Answer (score 0):

Also in Parody Doctors there’s:

- Erb Epic rap battles of history George w
  watsky 4th Doctor
- Erb Epic rap battles of history Nice Peter 10th Doctor

And many more, see [this What Culture article](http://whatculture.com/tv/7-doctor-who-tv-references-you-probably-didnt-know-about?page=7).

Comment: Im not quite sure if a parody actor really counts as an answer here but as it’s not specified one way or the other I won’t action it.